# How to make a Chronometer in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to add a chronometer to my Flutter project but didn't add a chronometer. Is a stopwatch enough for chronometer? How can I add a chronometer and use it in Flutter?

```
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find an article on how to build a stopwatch in Flutter. 
https://medium.com/@biz84/how-fast-is-flutter-i-built-a-stopwatch-app-to-find-out-9956fa0e40bd

```
void leftButtonPressed() {
setState(() {
  if (stopwatch.isRunning) {
    print("${stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds}");
  } else {
    stopwatch.reset();
  }
});
```

}

Vote if helps!

Comment: Thank you :)  I will try

Comment: i cant run :( because i would add in my project and it is could be work every page but i couldnt. Now i am developing php and I'm a little busy but i will try again later..